# How to render consistency in using appropriate webfont on various browsers and OS?

Tags: css, fonts, web, typography

I made a website using webfont, in *Fontsquirrel*.

```
@font-face 
{   
    font-family: 'Univers57Condensed';  
    src: url('/resources/fonts/univers-condensed-webfont.eot');     
    src: url('/resources/fonts/univers-condensed-webfont.eot?#iefix') 
    format('embedded-opentype'), 
    url('/resources/fonts/univers-condensed-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('http://hcil.snu.ac.kr/~muclipse/resources/fonts/univers-condensed-webfont.ttf')
    format('truetype'), 
    url('/resources/fonts/univers-condensed-webfont.svg#Univers57Condensed')
    format('svg');  
    font-weight: normal;    
    font-style: normal; 
}
```

I imported eot, woff, svg, ttf files like above.

Actually, it works fine, but I see some problems.

IE seems to load eot file always, but Google Chrome seems to load random files unpredictably.

> [image: Chrome, in MacOS]

Chrome, in MasOS, ordinary condition, but sometimes texts are rendered fatter.

> [image]

I guess the difference in rendering font is caused by loading different font file, isn't it?

How can I solve this problem, importing only eot and another format?

Comment: No, the difference is in the OS. And that's something you can't do anything about.

Answer (score 0):

The real reason for this difference, I suspect, is simply that different operating systems render fonts differently. The same font will look slightly different on Windows, OS X and Linux - and even within an OS, will change depending on settings (on Windows, you can see this if you enable / disable ClearType).

Basically, pixel-perfect similarity is impossible across different platforms.